# Capacity and indexFor in Java Hashmap

Tags: java, hash, hashmap, hashtable

While going through the source code of Java `HashMap`, we can see the first bucket for a key is determined with the method as below:

```
 static int indexFor(int h, int length) { //h = hash of key 
     return h & (length-1);               //length = capacity of array at 
 }                                        //         current time
```

As per my understanding if initial size is `16` (length-1 = 15 = 1111) and if the generated hash of a key `k1` is `108378` (1 10100111 01011010), then 
`indexFor()` method will return `10` (1010).

Now, say after some addition the capacity has changed to `32`. Now if I want to search for key `k1` (with hash 108378), it will again go to check the bucket with same `indexFor()` method. Now the `h & (length-1)` code snippet will return `26`. (108378 & 31).

My question is how will this get method will find the correct bucket, if the table get resized?

Comment: The buckets get restructured when the table is resized.

Comment: When the table is resized, all of the hash values for the keys are recalculated and moved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the maximum threshold of load factor is reached the process called Rehashing occurs and all the elements moved to a new table.

> When the number of entries in the hash table exceeds the product of
>   the load factor and the current capacity, the hash table is
>   *rehashed* (that is, internal data structures are rebuilt) so
>   that the hash table has approximately twice the number of buckets.
>
> The expected number of entries in the map and its load factor
>   should be taken into account when setting its initial capacity, so
>   as to minimize the number of rehash operations.

Comment: Thanks. In extension to your answer I have another question. If chaining is already applied, during rehashing, is it going to recalculate bucket # for the chained nodes also? Or just the start node of the chained nodes?

Comment: Recalculating occurs for all values, because nodes which hold the same bucket position before - now can be spread in different bucket positions.

Answer (score 1):

If the table gets resized, then the length parameter will change and the `indexFor` method will return a different value. When the table gets resized, the values that are currently in the table must be moved into the new table, therefore a new index will be computed for each of the values.

Comment: Okay...I got it. Thanks. But what surprises me is the time and space complexity when it is getting resized. It is not following O(n) complexity i believe during the operation.

Comment: @AnirbanB during a rehash the time complexity is O(n) because all of the elements that were in the old hash table must have a new hash code calculated, then an index calculated, then placed in the new table. It is not as efficient as adding a single element but it is still O(n).

Comment: Yeah...just realized actually it is O(n). But average case scenario is O(1). However space complexity is much larger than O(n).

Answer (score 0):

The `length` that you are seeing is not the value reported by `map.size()`. It is an internal length which represents the size of the hash table.  This length can be smaller than `size()` in a densely populated hash map, or it may be larger than `size()` in a sparsely populated hash map.  The smaller it is, the more keys will be found to have identical evaluations for `h & (length-1)` which means that the more keys will be grouped in buckets.

At some (hopefully as rare as possible) point in time the map decides that `length` is too small, causing too many collisions, (too many keys in each bucket,) so it *reorganizes* the map, reallocating the hash table to a larger size, recomputing all hash values, and re-distributing keys in buckets so that `h & (length-1)` is still correct for all hash values.